# How to solve error when querying the .shp file to Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

I am making a Python code with geopandas and xlwings, what I do is colsulse .shp files from Excel, it works fine but when it reaches the last line of the code wb.save (in_file) where it should be saved The Excel workbook, Excel restarts or closes unexpectedly, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, besides that if I remove that line and when trying to save the Excel workbook manually, the same thing happens.

The code is:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
from pathlib import Path

#VINCULACION_S
in_file = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("VINCULACION_S.xlsm"))
wb = xw.Book(in_file)

#VINCULACION_SH_NUE
sht1 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_NUE']
in_features1 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_NUE.shp"))
shp1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features1, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp1 = shp1[['COLOR', 'INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'COUNT_AREA', 'SUM_AREA', 'SUM_LENGTH']]
shp1.insert(3, "CIV", '', allow_duplicates=False)

urow1 = sht1.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht1.range("5" + ":" + str(urow1)).clear_contents()
sht1.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp1

#VINCULACION_SH_ACT
sht2 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_ACT']
in_features2 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_ACT.shp"))
shp2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features2, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp2 = shp2[['COLOR', 'INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'COUNT_AREA', 'SUM_AREA', 'SUM_LENGTH']]

urow2 = sht2.range('C2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht2.range("5" + ":" + str(urow2)).clear_contents()
sht2.range('C2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp2

#VINCULACION_SH_CIV
sht3 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_CIV']
in_features3 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_CIV.shp"))
shp3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features3, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp3 = shp3[['INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'MVICIV']]

urow3 = sht3.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht3.range("5" + ":" + str(urow3)).clear_contents()
sht3.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp3

#VINCULACION_SV_NUE
sht4 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_NUE']
in_features4 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV.shp"))
shp4 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features4, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp4 = shp4[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'FASE_ACCIO', 'CONTENIDO1', 'CONTENIDO2', 'VELOCIDAD']]
shp4.insert(2, "CIV", '', allow_duplicates=False)

urow4 = sht4.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht4.range("5" + ":" + str(urow4)).clear_contents()
sht4.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp4

#VINCULACION_SV_ACT
sht5 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_ACT']
in_features5 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV_ACT.shp"))
shp5 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features5, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp5 = shp5[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'FASE_ACCIO']]

urow5 = sht5.range('C2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht5.range("5" + ":" + str(urow5)).clear_contents()
sht5.range('C2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp5

#VINCULACION_SV_CIV
sht6 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_CIV']
in_features6 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV_CIV.shp"))
shp6 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features6, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp6 = shp6[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'MVICIV']]

urow6 = sht6.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht6.range("5" + ":" + str(urow6)).clear_contents()
sht6.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp6

wb.save(in_file)
```

It throws me this error, after having unexpectedly restarted or closed Excel

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Ejemplo\VINCULACION_S.py", line 72, in <module>
    wb.save(in_file)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 740, in save
    self.impl.save(path)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 552, in save
    self.xl.SaveAs(os.path.realpath(path), FileFormat=file_format)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 66, in __call__
    v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 46533, in SaveAs
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(3174, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (3, 49), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023170, 'Error en la llamada a procedimiento remoto.', None, None)
```

***Update***: What I have tried so far and it works is to separate the code for each procedure of shp and sht, that is, I execute in a different .py selecting the excel sheet where the result will go and in this way it does it well, I am trying to add an instruction to the python code where in each # ... select the excel sheet to process and continue until saving.

Comment: Book.save(path) is "Save as ..."; may be this doesn't work using the unchanged, already opened file name. Just try wb.save() without parameter.

Comment: @Redoute 
try wb.save () and it gives error and unexpectedly closes the excel file, which has worked for me put it in the question body as an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the error occurred because two or more sheets with rank in the code were activated, I solved it by adding the code in each # ... sht = wb.sheets ['name_of_the_sheet_to_process']. activate ()

I share the resulting and functional code, I hope someone will find this post useful

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
from pathlib import Path

#VINCULACION_S
in_file = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("VINCULACION_S.xlsm"))
wb = xw.Book(in_file)

#VINCULACION_SH_NUE
sht1 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_NUE'].activate()
sht1 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_NUE']
in_features1 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_NUE.shp"))
shp1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features1, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp1 = shp1[['COLOR', 'INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'COUNT_AREA', 'SUM_AREA', 'SUM_LENGTH']]
shp1.insert(3, "CIV", '', allow_duplicates=False)

urow1 = sht1.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht1.range("5" + ":" + str(urow1)).clear_contents()
sht1.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp1

#VINCULACION_SH_ACT
sht2 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_ACT'].activate()
sht2 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_ACT']
in_features2 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_ACT.shp"))
shp2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features2, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp2 = shp2[['COLOR', 'INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'COUNT_AREA', 'SUM_AREA', 'SUM_LENGTH']]

urow2 = sht2.range('C2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht2.range("5" + ":" + str(urow2)).clear_contents()
sht2.range('C2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp2

#VINCULACION_SH_CIV
sht3 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_CIV'].activate()
sht3 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_CIV']
in_features3 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_CIV.shp"))
shp3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features3, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp3 = shp3[['INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'MVICIV']]

urow3 = sht3.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht3.range("5" + ":" + str(urow3)).clear_contents()
sht3.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp3

#VINCULACION_SV_NUE
sht4 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_NUE'].activate()
sht4 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_NUE']
in_features4 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV.shp"))
shp4 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features4, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp4 = shp4[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'FASE_ACCIO', 'CONTENIDO1', 'CONTENIDO2', 'VELOCIDAD']]
shp4.insert(2, "CIV", '', allow_duplicates=False)

urow4 = sht4.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht4.range("5" + ":" + str(urow4)).clear_contents()
sht4.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp4

#VINCULACION_SV_ACT
sht5 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_ACT'].activate()
sht5 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_ACT']
in_features5 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV_ACT.shp"))
shp5 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features5, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp5 = shp5[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'FASE_ACCIO']]

urow5 = sht5.range('C2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht5.range("5" + ":" + str(urow5)).clear_contents()
sht5.range('C2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp5

#VINCULACION_SV_CIV
sht6 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_CIV'].activate()
sht6 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_CIV']
in_features6 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV_CIV.shp"))
shp6 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features6, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp6 = shp6[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'MVICIV']]

urow6 = sht6.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht6.range("5" + ":" + str(urow6)).clear_contents()
sht6.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp6

wb.save(in_file)
```